# Configuring Team Foundation Server 2010 for Multiple Users

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, team-foundation-server

We currently have a machine that is part of our Active Directory that is running a Windows Server 2008 R2 instance within Hyper-V VM. This VM is running Team Foundation Server 2010. As it stands, TFS has been configured for use on a single machine (small number of users) using more or less most of the defaults along with advice from the TFS install guide.

Currently, I can access the server using the admin account that was initially setup when TFS was configured. There are no issues accessing this either within the VM OS, in the host OS or from my local machine. As it stands, this is the only user account that has access to TFS. None of the users within our Active Directory can access it unless they use the admin account. Obviously, this is would be a terrible thing to do.

How can I set up my VM and/or TFS so that I can add all the developer credentials as-is from Active Directory and set up the appropriate permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the TFS documentation. Seriously.

You need to create a project, then give users rights in the project. This can be done within visual studio. Oncea developer is a developer for a project, he can also access it.

This is basics for TFS (only the start, it gets a lot more complicated after), so if you had no idea how rights management works, you are in for a world of pain soon.

Answer (score 0):

In the tfs admin tool, on the main page, there is UI for adding additional user accounts to the console. Once you add a name, the tool applies permissions to tfs, SharePoint, and SQL server RS (if necessary).

This will enable others to access the tfs admin tool. You'll still want to create a team project and add developers to that project, if you haven't done that.

Good luck.